# System.Data.Linq.Mapping.AttributedMetaDataMember High memory consumption

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql, garbage-collection

I'm analyzing the dump file for the Windows service project, and it is using LinqToSQL to connect databases. Attached dumpe heap memory analysis summary.

I can see the **System.Data.Linq.Mapping.AttributedMetaDataMember** taking more memory and It's resides in Gen2 bucket.

Can anyone guide me why it's taking more memory here?

Sample Code

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var detailsDataContext = new DetailsContext();
        var details = detailsDataContext.GetDetails(//param);
    }
}

public class DetailsContext
{
    private readonly IDetailsDataContextRepository _detailsDataContextRepository;

    public DetailsContext()
    {
        _detailsDataContextRepository = new DetailsDataContextRepository();
    }

    public Details GetDetails(string id)
    {
        try
        {
            List<Details> detailsList = _detailsDataContextRepository.GetDetails(id)?.ToList();
            if (detailsList != null && detailsList.Count > 0)
            {
                Detail detail = detailsList.FirstOrDefault();
                return detailsList;
            }

            return null;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Error log
            return null;
        }
    }

}

public class DetailsDataContextRepository : DataContext, IDetailsDataContextRepository
{

    [Function(Name = "dbo.sp_GetDetails")]
    public IEnumerable<Details> GetDetails([Parameter(Name = "Id", DbType = "VARCHAR(255)")] string id)
    {
        try
        {
            IExecuteResult result = this.ExecuteMethodCall(this, ((MethodInfo)(MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod())), id);
            ISingleResult<Details> mRecord = ((ISingleResult<Details>)(result.ReturnValue));
            return mRecord;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            TraceError("DetailsDataContext", "GetDetails", ex);
            return new List<Details>();
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in Advance.
[image]

Comment: Can say much anything without seeing some code, but ime the most common reason is calling `ToList()` too often.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Thanks and updated code. Can you check now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll focus on `DetailsContext.GetDetails(string id)` method as one example of how to improve things.

Instead of this:

```
public Details GetDetails(string id)
{
    try
    {
        List<Details> detailsList = _detailsDataContextRepository.GetDetails(id)?.ToList();
        if (detailsList != null && detailsList.Count > 0)
        {
            Detail detail = detailsList.FirstOrDefault();
            return detailsList;
        }

        return null;

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //Error log
        return null;
    }
}
```

You can get equivalent functionality like this:

```
public Details GetDetails(string id)
{
    try
    {
        return _detailsDataContextRepository.GetDetails(id).FirstOrDefault();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //Error log
        return null;
    }
}
```

Not only is this MUCH less code, but it's faster and far more memory efficient. As mentioned in the comment, one of the main improvements here is eliminating the spurious `ToList()` call, which accomplished *nothing* useful. I see a lot of programmers adopt this crutch, and learning to work without it can **dramatically** help your code.

Furthermore, based on a review of the repository's `GetDetails()` method, I might also remove the `try/catch` block, since that method itself uses a try/catch around anything that's likely to throw and provides a sensible default. It means we can **safely** get down to this one-liner with *no loss of function*:

```
public Details GetDetails(string id)
{
    return _detailsDataContextRepository.GetDetails(id).FirstOrDefault();
}
```